# Remove autoconf dependency for glog

Tags: compilation, autoconf

I want to use the Google Logging Library (glog, https://github.com/google/glog) but it depends on the autoconf tools. How can I now disable the use of autoconf when I compile glog? Or maybe it is possible to use autoconf ONCE and then remove the dependency or disable autoconf for all following compilation runs. I just couldn't figure out how to do this...Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use the Google Logging Library (glog, https://github.com/google/glog) but it depends on the autoconf tools. How can I now disable the use of autoconf when I compile glog?

Probably not, if it depends on autotools.

> Or maybe it is possible to use autoconf ONCE and then remove the dependency or disable autoconf for all following compilation runs.

Sure, there's a few ways of doing this.  The easiest is: [Use a package](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/google-glog).   The next easiest (if you need more up to date features) is grab a code snapshot and `configure; make; make install` to your own system which will install the libs/headers (in `/usr/local/lib` in this instance, which can be adjusted).   If you don't want to do that, you can always relocate where libs/headers get installed: `configure; make; make DESTDIR=/some/dir install`.  Then there's using packaging sources (and a code snapshot) and making your own package.